# How should we place custom button in google map?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

By clicking on a button am navigating to google maps app, and there am showing directions from one location to another location. Here is the code which i wrote in button

```
@IBAction func movetonextclass() {
     if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "comgooglemaps://")!) {
        let googleMapUrlString: String = "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(CDouble(reachLat)),\(CDouble(reachLong))&mode=driving"
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: googleMapUrlString)!)
    }
    else {
         print("i wont go to google maps app, because in ur device there is no google maps app")
    }   
}
```

now am navigating to google maps app.

Here i would like to display a custom button in that screen.

Now, if i click on that button, i should navigate to my own app

how should i put a button in google maps screen? could any one help me with this

Comment: you cant handle this,

Comment: @anbu is it possible to show directions from one location to another location and turn by turn navigation ?

Comment: if you are used this `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL`, just you set the source and desitantion

Comment: i can show directions(path) in may app. but i also want to show turn-by-turn navigation in the map

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i want to show turn-by-turn navigation in my app itself

Comment: see this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rVmxXpI28zU